# Smith Normal Form for block matrices over the integers

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, chain-complexes, smith-normal-form, block-matrices

Are there any known results on the Smith Normal Form for block matrices over the integers?

In particular, I am interested in matrices of size $kr \times ks$ made of square blocks of size $k$ such that each block has one $1$ and one $-1$ in each row and column and the rest are zeros. This is for computing the cohomology of a certain chain complex.

Comment: What kind of results? Special properties of the Smith form in that case? Efficient computation? A "block-Smith" variant that works on the matrix ring of $k\times k$ matrices?

Comment: I would like to prove that this kind of matrix have always the same type of smith normal form: an identity matrix and than only zeros.

Answer (score 3):

[On efficient sparse integer matrix Smith normal form computations](http://ljk.imag.fr/membres/Jean-Guillaume.Dumas/Publications/valence.pdf) (Dumas, Saunders, Villard, 2001)

> We present a new algorithm to compute the Integer Smith normal form of
>   large sparse matrices. We reduce the computation of the Smith form to
>   independent, and therefore parallel, computations modulo powers of
>   word-size primes. Our method has
>   proven useful in algebraic topology for the computation of the
>   homology of some large simplicial complexes.